# Oracle FETCH FIRST 1 ROW with UNION ALL statement

Tags: sql, oracle, union

I'm trying to create a UNION ALL statement in SQL using the FETCH FIRST 1 ROW however when I do that it gives me an error `MISSING KEYWORD`

Here's what my SQL looks like:

```
Select * From tabl1 where Date = '04-MAR-2020' FETCH FIRST 1 ROW

UNION ALL

Select * From tabl1 where Date = '05-MAR-2020' FETCH FIRST 1 ROW
```

is something like this doable. I would like to keep this as a single statement rather than adding a SUBQUERY or anything of that nature.

Comment: This query seems to be missing an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @GMB I added ORDER BY DATE and it still gives same error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just put each part in parentheses.  Works in 12.2, anyway:

```
( Select * From tabl1 where Date = '04-MAR-2020' FETCH FIRST 1 ROW )
UNION ALL
( Select * From tabl1 where Date = '05-MAR-2020' FETCH FIRST 1 ROW )
```

My actual test query, for anyone interested was this:

```
(select   object_name 
 from     user_objects 
 where    object_type = 'TABLE' 
 order by object_name 
 fetch first 1 row only)
UNION ALL
(select   object_name 
 from     user_objects 
 where    object_type = 'VIEW' 
 order by object_name 
 fetch first 1 row only);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `row_number()` instead:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where date in (date '2020-03-04', date '2020-03-05')
order by row_number() over(partition by trunc(date) order by date)
fetch first 1 row with ties
```

`row_number()` puts each *day* in a different partition, and orders records of each day by ascending date. You can then use the row limiting clause with the `with ties` option to get the first record per day.

This is more efficient than the `union all` solution, because it scans the table only once.

---

If you *do* want `union all`, then you can do:

```
select *
from (
    (select * from tabl1 where date = date '2020-03-04' order by date fetch first 1 row)
    union all
    (select * from tabl1 where date = date '2020-03-05' order by date fetch first 1 row)
)
```

Comment: is there any way to have this look like my statement. With an actual UNION ALL?

Comment: Efficiency is not the issue here. I need the statement to look like I have in the question. I just need to only fetch 1 row from each of the statements

Comment: @Koosh You can't have a separate `order by` for individual sections of a `union` query, even if you fix the `fetch first` syntax. You can only have one at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Select * From tabl1 where Date = '04-MAR-2020' and ROWNUM <= 1
UNION ALL
Select * From tabl1 where Date = '05-MAR-2020' and ROWNUM <= 1
```

Comment: Note that `ROWNUM` doesn't respect `ORDER BY`.