# SQL command not properly ended union

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my error message:

[image]

This is the text

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle FETCH FIRST 1 ROW with UNION ALL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61106222/oracle-fetch-first-1-row-with-union-all-statement)

Comment: Your question was correct the first time.  Text is much preferred instead of images.

Comment: Many sites block links. Many of us refuse to open them for the same reason others block them.  You should always past code directly into your messages.  And as @GordonLinoff said, actual text (formatted) is much preferable to images. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Oracle requires parentheses for the subqueries:

```
(select TeamName As Name, points As points
 from standing
 group by TeamName, points
 having Length(TeamName) >= 3 and points > 5
 order by points DESC, TeamName ASC
 Fetch first 2 rows only
) union 
(select TeamName As Name, points As points
 from standing 
 group by TeamName, points
 having Length(TeamName) >= 3 and points > 5
 order by points ASC
 Fetch first 1 rows only
)
```

The parentheses are needed when the subqueries have either `order by` or `fetch` clauses.  They are needed to distinguish between applying those clauses to an individual subquery or to the results of the entire `union`.

Also, you might want `union all` instead of `union` -- `union` incurs overhead for removing duplicates.